Make Particles while building object
I want to make an object build with particles streaming off the built part. The only way I know how, though, is in 2D animation, and it's long and tedious. It needs to work with 3D objects, using a particle system and (most likely) the Build modifier. I have a .gif that (hopefully) demonstrates what I am trying to do. The black is for the object, and the red is for the particles. (Yes, I know the 2D animation is awful.) Is there an automated process for this?


is that [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/V0Laopwt.gif what you are trying to achieve?

maybe you could try with a Boolean modifier + particles?

@Chris Sort of, except that I want the particles to fly around. Maybe with a turbulence force field? Also, it should stop the particles at the end of the building, not continue producing.

@moonboots I've tried that, but with no success.

is it not a variation of this effect? https://youtu.be/72IJGg_D5IY

@moonboots Yes, but in reverse. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

You could simply reverse the animation in the Video Sequencer   ;)

@moonboots I don't know. I've already mentioned this in an above comment, but the particles need to fly around. It would look weird for the particles to come out of nowhere and fly to the place it is supposed to start (a.k.a. the building object).
